# WCF FaultException <T> (fault contract) - .NET Core 2.2

Tags: wcf, .net-core-2.2

Is faultcontracts with FaultException< T > not supported in .NET Core 2.2?

I have a WCF service reference like so - this exact code is not tested, but simular works well in .NET Standard 4.6.2.

Server side:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(MyErrorType))]
[WebInvoke(
      Method = "GET",
      UriTemplate = "/GetData?foo={foo}",
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
      RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
ExpectedReturnType GetData(int foo);
```

---

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class MyErrorType
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
try {
   return GetData(123);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new FaultException<MyErrorType>(new MyErrorType() { ErrorCode  = 20,  Description = "Server side error message returning to client" });
}
```

Client side

```
try 
{
   _client.GetData(123);
}
catch (FaultException <MyErrorType> e)
{
  // NEVER ENDS UP HERE IN .NET Core 2.2
  // works fine in .NET Standard 4.6.2 
  Console.WriteLine(e.Details.ErrorCode);
  Console.WriteLine(e.Details.Description);
  throw e;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  throw e;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled over the same problem now myself. For now I did this workaround that seems to work for me.

```
catch (FaultException<WarehouseFault> faultException) 
{
    // FaultException is not supported in .Net Core as far as I know. 
    // So for now code is moved in general Exception handling below which seems to work.
    throw new Exception(".Net Core now seem to support FaultException!");
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    if (e.InnerException is FaultException<WarehouseFault> faultException) { 
        // Handle the fault exception here.
    }

    // Other exceptions
}
```